# why sonar - dot net ecosystem default tests failing?

Tags: sonarqube

I got the latest code (zip) from [sonar .neteco system](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-dotnet) and did mvn install on the root directory. It starts the build and runs the tests. When it hits .Net tools: Gendarme Runner, it fails with "Impossible to copy Silverlight MScorlib.dll as there is no existing file. But I was able to locate the file under runner/SilverlightFolder. I checked the CI environment for the project and it seems to green all the way. Is there anything I am missing here? I am not a java person so I do not know how to step into test to see which directory is it looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not a Java developer, why are you trying to build the Sonar .NET Ecosystem? If you just want to install the .NET & C# plugins, you simply have to head to the [documentation page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C#+Plugins+Ecosystem) and follow the installation procedure.

Comment: Thanks. In my case the problem was eclipse was using jre rather than jdk. So when I changed it to JDK all the errors gone.